# Should I need to consider the cold start time of Cloud Run when I set the minimun instance to 1?

Tags: google-cloud-run

Following the documentation below, the cold start only happens on scaling 0 to 1.

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips/general#starting_containers_quickly

Is it means that I don't need to consider the cold start time when I set the minimum instance to 1?

Comment: Yes, but you will also pay for idle instances (you reserve CPU and Memory for your min instances, so you have to pay for it)

Comment: @mayTree "Feel free to upvote or accept if my answer is satisfied"